# Cygwin: unable to issue R CMD SHLIB foo.c

Tags: r, cygwin

I am relatively new to R, and have no experience with Linux or C. I need to compile a .c program that I can later call from R.  I installed Cygwin, and used the cd command to change to the R/R-2.14.0/bin directory.  I verified this using the ls command.  I also copied the foo.c program into the same directory. However, when I attempt to execute the "R CMD SHLIB foo.c" command I get the following error message:

-bash: R: command not found

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Yes.  You need to read the documentation.  Start with `?SHLIB`.  Then investigate the manuals referenced in the "See Also" section of `?SHLIB` ([R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html) and [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)).

Comment: I have read the documentation, but much of it addresses creating a package, which I didn't think I needed to do.  I just need to compile the program into a shared object (.so) file.  Is it possible to just compile the program into a shared object that I can later load into R, without having to create a package?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  I pointed you to the documentation because you don't even have the necessary tools.  I don't know why you installed Cygwin but searching the manuals for "Cygwin" would have shown that you needed to install [The Windows Toolset](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset).  I encourage you to find someone to walk you through this because you're going to run into a ton of problems given you don't know how to run a command in *nix, let alone compile a program.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that was all I needed to know (that I needed to use RTools).  I was using a hardcover reference, that recommended Cygwin.. but that turned out to be a dead-end for me. I installed RTools, and was able to compile the program, load it into R and execute it.